# how to select data from three tables in a single select query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have three tables in my database as below:

Table A : Column1 primary key, column 2 foriegn key, column 3 foriegn key, column 4

Table B : Column 1 primary key (column 2 in table A), Column 2

Table C : Column 1 primary key (column 3 in table A), Column 2

Now I want a query to extract data from table A all four columns and column 2 of other two tables on where clause from table A, Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use join

```
select A.*, B.column2 as column2B, c.column2 as column2C
from tableA a join tableb b on a.column2=b.column1
join tableC c on a.column3=c.column1
```

Comment: Left join may not be necessary if the foreign keys are `not null`, plus OP may not want rows from A where no matching rows are in B/C. However, this answer is basically correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
select a.column1, a.column2, a.column3, a.column4, b.column2, c.column2
from TableA a left join TableB b on a.column2 = b.column1 
              left join TableC c on a.column3 = c.column1
```

More on left join here:

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Answer (score 1):

use left join

```
select a.*,b.*,c.* from tableA a left join tableB b on a.column2=b.column1
            left join tableC c on a.column2=c.column3
```